# Issue When Moving Object to Specific Position Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object that I want to move slowly & smoothly to a specific position when clicking, so I used this code:

```
currpos = transform.position;
Vector3 NewPos = new Vector3(- 10, currpos.y, currpos.z + 2);
Rigidbody.MovePosition(Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, NewPos, Time.deltaTime* MoveSpeed)) ;
```

The problem I have is when the MoveSpeed is low the object move a little bit and didn't reach the specific position, and when increasing the MoveSpeed he reach the specific position but quickly! do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Have you enabled Rigidbody interpolation?

Comment: No, I tried it right now but the issue still exist

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check it now.

Answer (score 0):

> public static Vector3 Lerp(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, float t);
>
> Interpolates between the vectors a and b by the interpolant t. The
> parameter t is clamped to the range [0, 1]. This is most commonly used
> to find a point some fraction of the way along a line between two
> endpoints.

As the Doc says, it is some fraction instead of distance. The logic isn't right.

So the code could be revised as follows:

```cs
 currpos = transform.position;
 Vector3 NewPos = new Vector3(- 10, currpos.y, currpos.z + 2);
 Vector3 Dir= (NewPos-transform.position).normalized;
 Vector3 velocity= Dir*MoveSpeed;
 Rigidbody.MovePosition(transform.position+velocity);
```

If you insist using Lerp:

```cs
   currpos = transform.position;
   Vector3 NewPos = new Vector3(- 10, currpos.y, currpos.z + 2);
   float dist= (NewPos-transform.position).magnitude;
   if(dist!=0)
   {
        Rigidbody.MovePosition(Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, NewPos, Time.deltaTime* MoveSpeed)) ;   
   }
   else
   {
           //do nothing new postion arrived
   }
```

Comment: I tried the two codes you give me, but the problem still exist, the object move fast when increasing MoveSpeed, and didn't reach the new position when decreasing MoveSpeed!

Comment: @Taik Is there any simple demo I can download? I dont have enough info to debug.

Comment: How can I do it?

Comment: Perhaps a link to a your demo without expose your personal info or assets.

Comment: is there any other method to move the object slowly?

Answer (score 0):

According to Unity3D [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) on Rigidbody.MovePosition you need to enable Rigidbody interpolation for smooth transition between the two positions. This should also be done in the FixedUpdate like this:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.forward * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

The Rigidbody.MovePosition takes just one parameter which is the destination Vector3. You should just specify destination point without the Lerping so try this instead:

```
Rigidbody.MovePosition(NewPos + Time.deltaTime * MoveSpeed);
```

And do it in the FixedUpdate. Also:

> If the rigidbody has isKinematic set false then it works differently. It works like transform.position=newPosition and teleports the object (rather than a smooth transition).

Answer (score 0):

Lerp Function gives a point between 2 Vectors everytime you call it, so just like the turtle problem, it will never reach to destionation. It will get slower and slower each time.

You can eliminate this behaviour with fixing travel speed to a constant but it will not look as good as slowing gradually as approach.

Also you can eliminate this behaviour with stopping the object after it gets too close to object, (that is how i use it usually)

Also note that, if you want to animate someting with code and you want it to be smooth you have to calculate it on "Update" Function.

So the code can be something like

```
void GoToTarget(){
    var currpos = transform.position;
    NewPos = new Vector3(- 10, currpos.y, currpos.z + 2);
    traveling = true;
}

void Update () {
    if (traveling){
        rigidbody.MovePosition(Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, NewPos, Time.deltaTime* MoveSpeed));
        if((transform.position-NewPos).magnitude < 0.1f){
            //Current position is too close to Target, teleport to target and stop
            transform.position = NewPos;
            traveling = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than lerping, why not just move towards it?

```
currpos = transform.position;
Vector3 NewPos = new Vector3(- 10, currpos.y, currpos.z + 2);
var position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, NewPos, Time.deltaTime* MoveSpeed);
Rigidbody.MovePosition(position);
```